# I'm having issues printing some concatenated strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

```
var quotePt1 = "Excellence is an art won by training and    
                habituation.";
var quotePt2 = "We do not act rightly because we have virtue or     
                excellence,";
var quotePt3 = "but we rather have those because we have acted 
                rightly.";
var quotePt4 = "We are what we repeatedly do.";
var quotePt5 = "Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.";
var qouteFull = quotePt1.concat(quotePt2+quotePt3+quotePt4+quotePt5);
```

**I'm trying to assign the full quote name to be 'quoteFull' and then print the entire quote**

Comment: you can concatenate by `+` sign

Comment: So? Where's your printing code? And what's the issue?

Comment: @uzaif or by [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

Comment: Maybe it's just the misspelling of `qoute`?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? They've asked a specific question, who are you all to judge why they're wanting to do it in such a way? Perhaps try answering the question instead of commenting.

Comment: @gotnull: if you found a question in the post, can you tell us what it is?

Comment: @Bergi: Perhaps you're blind, so I'll comment it here: **I'm trying to assign the full quote name to be 'quoteFull' and then print the entire quote**.

Comment: @gotnull: That's a statement, not a question. There is nothing to be solved here.

Comment: @Bergi: Righto, fair enough.

Comment: a troll... seriously?? I'm obviously new at JS and need help figuring what I'm doing wrong.  It's an honest question.  if u don't want to help ppl get off the site.  What ever happened to compassion and generosity? @gotnull thank you for your kindness.  Learning something new is hard and then putting myself out there to ask a question only to be ridiculed is even harder.

Comment: to the point i used the + sign w concat bc I saw that it as an example.  If you can provide a workable solution/correction to my code I would appreciate it.  thanks

Comment: @CelestineDew You're welcome. Unfortunately there are a lot of people who are of no help and spread like a virus on SO. Hopefully my answer or someone else's helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're aware of all your spelling mistake.

Putting that aside, why not just concatenate them using `+`, rather than using `concat()`?

```js
var quotePt1 = "Excellence is an art won by training and habituation. ";

var quotePt2 = "We do not act rightly because we have virtue or excellence, ";

var quotePt3 = "but we rather have those because we have acted rightly. ";

var quotePt4 = "We are what we repeatedly do. ";

var quotePt5 = "Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.";

var qouteFull = quotePt1 + quotePt2 + quotePt3 + quotePt4 + quotePt5;

console.log(qouteFull);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other respondents answered, to concatenate strings in JavaScript, use the **+**.

However, the variables named with an incrementing integer looks like an array to me, and it could be coded like so:

```
var quotePts = ["Excellence is an art won by training and habituation.",
    "We do not act rightly because we have virtue or excellence,",
    "but we rather have those because we have acted rightly.",
    "We are what we repeatedly do.",
    "Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit."];
var quoteFull = quotePts.join("\n",quotePts);
console.log(quoteFull);
```

For completeness, if you want to use a multiline string, you can use a backslash at the end of each line, like so:

```
var quoteFull = "Excellence is an art won by training and habituation. \n\
We do not act rightly because we have virtue or excellence, \n\
but we rather have those because we have acted rightly. \n\
We are what we repeatedly do. \n\
Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.";
console.log(quoteFull);
```

Credit: https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings

Answer (score 0):

```
var quotePt1 = "Excellence is an art won by training and habituation.";
var quotePt2 = " We do not act rightly because we have virtue or     
                 excellence,";
var quotePt3 = " but we rather have those because we have acted  
                 rightly.";
var quotePt4 = " We are what we repeatedly do.";
var quotePt5 = " Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.";
var quoteFull = quotePt1 + quotePt2 + quotePt3 + quotePt4 + quotePt5;
```

console.log(quoteFull);

This is the correct answer.  FYI.  I just needed to correct my spelling and add a space in between the lines after the first quote.  I am working through a BLOC software Developer course and I think the course is very specific about syntax.  Whew!